# MSSQL Deadlocking preventing DDL statement in different DB from running

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, ddl, blocking

I had a user doing a massive SQL data compare from server A to server B involving database X.

On Server B, I was trying to run a CREATE SYNONYM statement in database Y, which was being entirely blocked -- as in the statement was running for approximately 20+ mins.  There were no open transactions in database Y on server B.

I was wondering what could be causing this, and if it is preventable via server configuration, so I can pass any information along to my sys admin and DBA.  Thanks in advance for any insight that might help performance.

According to sp_who2:

Create Synonym blocked by INSERT into master by me

INSERT into master by me blocked by INSERT into master by sa

INSERT into master by sa blocked by massive EXECUTE from other user (for SQL compare / sync)

Comment: If you can recreate this situation, install and run sp_whoisactive to determine why your process is waiting

Comment: @ScottHodgin Thanks for your reply -- let me know if the additional info I provided helps get to the bottom of this at all.  Luckily, I saved the dump from sp_who2